# Plugin update field from a related entity

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, crm

I want to build a plugin for updating a field from a related entity.
On Entity Agreement I have two fields: field A(look-up Account) and field B(look-up Contact)

I have to check if an option set field from Account(field A) is one specific value, then to update an option set field from Contact(field B).

That's all. Thanks!

Comment: Yes that's possible. What is your problem? what did you tried till now?

Comment: I can't figure out how to update that field from look-up Entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Entity agreement = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"]; // this is your target entity from which plugin is firing.

// Now do whatever your check you wish to perform

// once you are ready to update lookupAccount Record below code will work

  Entity lookupAccount = new Entity();
                    lookupAccount.LogicalName = "account";
                    lookupAccount.Id = agreement.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("field A").Id;
                    lookupAccount["optionSetFieldToUpdate"]= new OptionSetValue(1234);

                    orgService.Update(lookupAccount);



// In similar way you can perform update for ook-up Contact)


 Entity lookupContact = new Entity();
                    lookupContact.LogicalName = "contact";
                    lookupContact.Id = agreement.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("field B").Id;
                    lookupContact["optionSetFieldToUpdate"]= new OptionSetValue(1234);

                    orgService.Update(lookupContact);
```